# Converting stack from array to arrayList

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist, stack

I have a stack implementation that uses an array and i am trying to convert it to an array list. The array is top and arrayList is on bottom. Do these 2 segments of code do the same thing? I also have two segments of a pop method one array and one array list. But for this one i get an error that temp has not been initialized and cannot find symbol temp. Any help is appreciated thanks.

```
 USING ARRAY
public void push(T value)
    {     
        if(size==values.length)
            expandCapacity();

        values[size] = value;
        size++;
    }


 USING ARRAYLIST
 public void push(T value)
    {

        values.add(value);

        size++;
    }



USING ARRAY
public T pop()
    {    
        if(isEmpty())
            throw new RuntimeException("Attempt to pop from empty stack");

        size--;
        T temp = values[size];
        values[size] = null;
        return temp;
    }

 USING ARRAYLIST

public T pop()
    {
        T temp;

        if(isEmpty())
            throw new RuntimeException("Attempt to pop from empty stack");

        size--;

        values.add(temp);

         values.temp = null;
        //values[size] = null;
        return temp;

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `push` methods, for both your array and `ArrayList` versions look correct.  Your `pop` for an array looks good.  However, the `pop` for an `ArrayList` needs work.

You decrement `size`, which is good, but you are attempting to add `temp` (which is uninitialized), which doesn't make sense.

You'll need to call [`remove`, passing the index `size`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#remove%28int%29), which will return the necessary item that you can return in your `pop` method.

Comment: Take that call out; it doesn't even make sense in this context.  All you need is the call to `remove`.

Comment: That looks good.  Are you checking for an empty stack before accessing the array or calling `get`, like you are already checking in `pop`?

Comment: You left out very important parts of that stack trace -- the type of exception and the exception message.

Comment: You'll have to debug this yourself; without seeing your `peek` method, I cannot tell why that occurred.